# Are there any mnemonic aids for remembering how to deal with cases for each gender?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, learning

I always get confused remembering adjective endings for both definite and indefinite articles. Does anyone know of any phrases/songs that kids are taught at school to help with remembering these?

For example, as a kid I was taught to remember the rainbow colours by:

> Richard Of York Gave Battle In Vain

Comment: I was just about to write a long answer with the gist of ‘why should it exist — Germans can do it intuitively’. Then I realised that foreign language teachers of German might have ones like German English teachers always teach ‘*He, she, it – s* muss mit’. *Maybe* there is one or two written in German for *Deutsch als Fremdsprache* learners, if so, Emanuel might know them. But otherwise I would recommend you go and ask a German teacher at your local school. *They* would know.

Comment: @Jan I wouldn't say we (Germans) can do it entirely intuitively: In grade school we did have to learn those articles by heart (as a table). Admittedly though any *shortcuts* relied entirely on our language feeling. (Therefore I leave this as comment as it wouldn't be a helpful answer.)

Comment: @Jan... I don't know any :). And I don't think there exists one because the whole matter is just to big and messy. How do you want to condense 2 tables with 16 entries each and a fair degree of random into a nice song or rhyme. That would be more like an epic poem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is any song or poem to remember the case endings. However, I cannot be sure since to prove the absence of something is often much harder than to prove its existence. ;-)

In the end the only mnemonic aid is a table similar to the one that E.V. posted in her/his answer. 
**But:** It isn't as hard as it looks at first glance. There are some regularities that can be used to reduce the chart to a minimum.

---

**Differences between nominative and accusative**

- Neuter endings are always the same in nominative and accusative. Indeed, this is an Indo-european universal property: In every IE language I know this is the case.
- Plural endings are the same in nominative and accusative.
- Feminine endings are the same in nominative and accusative.

So the only difference between nominative and accusative which one has to learn lies in the masculine endings.

---

**Rare cases**

- The third column in E.V.'s table belongs to the strong declension. In singular, the strong declension is rarely used.
- The genitive in general is seldomly used in spoken German
- The mix of both, i.e. the genitive of the strong declension is hardly ever used. In fact I cannot think of one naturally sounding example, only artificial newspaper headlines (*Alten Mannes Frau entführt*). My advise: Strike out the genitive box for strong declension.

---

**Mixed declension is a mix of strong and weak declension**
The first column in E.V.'s table is called weak declension, the last column is the strong declension. The middle column is the mixed declension. You only have to learn when the mixed declension is identical to the strong and when to the weak declension. This reduces a bit the amount one has to learn.

---

**Consonants as case markers**
Some case-gender combinations have a special consonant as a marker. For example, the marker for *nominative, masculine* is the letter **r**. You'll see that it is present once in all three declension classes:

- De**r** große Hund. (No need to add an **r** to *große*, since *der* already has it.)
- Ein große**r** Hund. (*Ein* doesn't have the **r**, so you must attach it to *groß*.)
- Große**r** Hund. (Again, the **r** must be there.)

Another example: The *dative, neuter* marker is the letter **m**:

- De**m** großen Haus. (Not *großem*, because the article has the *m*.)
- Eine**m** großen Haus. (Not *großem*, because the article has the *m*.)
- Große**m** Haus. (We need the **m**, so we attach it to *groß*.)

Of course you then have to know the articles to see when the consonant marker is already there. And even if you see "ah, the **m** is already present in *einem*, so the adjective won't need it" you cannot tell if it then has to be *große* or *großen*; but at least you then know that it cannot be *einem großem Haus*.

Comment: Thanks Chris - your `consonants as case markers` is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for :) ...little tools/rules I can reference when I hear sentences 'in the wild' I can go over in my head to work out the gender of nouns I come across

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I did it. 
I used this summery and with time I practised, practised and practised. Making mistaked all the time and being corrected. 
I have no "easier" way to suggest

[image]

Comment: That's a great table thank you...I'm ashamed to say I wasn't even aware of the third declination....!